# Python If printed results are the same as before print no change otherwise print new results. Run again every 10 mins

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I want to run this script every 10 minutes and if the results are the same today I don't want to print them again unless they change. Is this even possible? No I'm not a programmer by any means this is just a hobby.

I'm using Twilio to send me a sms message for campsites that are available but I don't want to receive the same sms message every 10 minutes. I removed the Twilio code because it has my account info. Thank you in advance for any help. Here is my code below.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate


result = []
for unit_id in range(5095, 5099):
    resp = requests.get(
        f"https://calirdr.usedirect.com/rdr/rdr/fd/"
        f"availability/getbyunit/{unit_id}/startdate/2020-10-30/nights/30/true?").json()
    result.extend(resp)

filter_by = ['UnitId', 'StartTime', 'IsFree', 'IsWalkin']
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df = df.filter(items=filter_by)
df['StartTime'] = df['StartTime'].apply(lambda d: datetime.fromisoformat(d).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
df = df[df['IsFree']]
df = df[~df['IsWalkin']]
df['UnitId'] = df['UnitId'].replace([5095], 'Site 81')
df['UnitId'] = df['UnitId'].replace([5096], 'Site 82')
df['UnitId'] = df['UnitId'].replace([5097], 'Site 83')
df['UnitId'] = df['UnitId'].replace([5098], 'Site 84')
df['UnitId'] = df['UnitId'].replace([5099], 'Site 85')
print(tabulate(df, headers=filter_by))
```

Below are the results if you run the code.

```
    UnitId    StartTime    IsFree    IsWalkin
--  --------  -----------  --------  ----------
62  Site 83   2020-11-01   True      False
80  Site 83   2020-11-19   True      False
89  Site 83   2020-11-28   True      False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: _Is this even possible?_ Yes. Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run the programm, wait ten minutes, check if the previous result is the same as the current one and if yes, then quit. So the part for you is now to figure out, how to quit it only until the next day :)

//EDIT: I edited the code corresponding to your comment

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate
import time

def main():
    result = []
    for unit_id in range(5095, 5099):
        resp = requests.get(
        f"https://calirdr.usedirect.com/rdr/rdr/fd/"
        f"availability/getbyunit/{unit_id}/startdate/2020-10-30/nights/30/true?").json()
        result.extend(resp)

    filter_by = ['UnitId', 'StartTime', 'IsFree', 'IsWalkin']
    df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    df = df.filter(items=filter_by)
    df['StartTime'] = df['StartTime'].apply(lambda d: datetime.fromisoformat(d).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    df = df[df['IsFree']]
    df = df[~df['IsWalkin']]
    df['UnitId'] = df['UnitId'].replace([5095], 'Site 81')
    df['UnitId'] = df['UnitId'].replace([5096], 'Site 82')

    return tabulate(df, headers=filter_by)


res_before = ""
while True:
    res = main()
    if res != res_before:
        print(res)
        res_before = res
    else:
        print("nothing changed")
    time.sleep(600)
```

Comment: Error when running this code:     return tabulate(df, headers=filter_by)
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Looks like it's working now I had to move the result = [] above the def main(). The only probably is I don't want to program to end I want it to keep checking every 10 minutes and print the results if they change. Can that be done? Thanks

Comment: Does not seem to print any request when testing the code.

Comment: ok, i only kept `'Site 81'` and `'Site 82'`, you have to add the rest again right. check the website itself, did anything change there?